# What is a regex that will match a twitter screen name but ignore an email?

Tags: regex, twitter

I need to find a regex that would catch a screen name like `@cnn`, but ignore an email address like `john@cnn.com`.

Most of the regex I have seen would match both, for instance `^@?(\w){1,15}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

email addresses has a dot but in the twitter names, dot won't be present. So match the names which start with `@` and the following one or more characters but not of dot and it must be immediately followed by a space or line end anchor.

```
@[^.]+?(?=\s|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/21)

Answer (score 1):

`^@?(\w{1,15})$` cannot match `john@cnn.com` as there is not `.` matcher.`\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.So this regex should work for your case.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/19

Comment: Why the `?` after the `@`? It causes your pattern to match `foo`.

Comment: @Rawing that was the regex OP mentioned.He might need to match `foo`

Comment: Oh. Right. My bad. Guess I shouldn't go onto SO right after I wake up.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the output on the test site, but it appears to match the 'd' in the expression?